# Wann wünscht man jemandem eine "gute Zeit"?

Tags: phrase

Wann sagt man zu jemandem

> Gute Zeit!

und was bedeutet die Aussage genau? Geht man davon aus, dass man sich lange nicht mehr sehen wird und dem anderen für eine unbestimmte Zeit alles Gute wünscht? Kann man es sagen, wenn man weiß, dass man die Person in z.B. einem Monat wiedersehen wird?

Das habe ich in unterschiedlichen Kontexten gehört. Z.B. hat es mir eine Kollegin gewünscht, nachdem ich mit meinem Praktikum fertig wurde und mich verabschiedet habe.
Gestern habe ich gehört, wie eine ältere Dame es einem älteren Paar auf der Straße gewünscht hat (wahrscheinlich kennen sie sich).

Und eine zusätzliche Frage gleich: Wie kann man darauf antworten? Kann man "Gleichfalls" sagen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich nehme an, du hast das in Süddeutschland gehört?

> Ich wünsche Dir/Ihnen eine gute Zeit

Ist ein typischer finaler Abschiedsgruss im Schwäbischen, wenn man sich von jemandem relativ endgültig verabschiedet, den man mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit nie wieder oder lange nicht wieder sehen wird (Also eine Art mundartliche Version von "Lebe wohl"). Auch im Schwäbischen ist dieser Abschiedsgruß ein bißchen aus der Mode gekommen und man wird ihn eher von älteren Leuten zu hören bekommen. Die Schwaben, deren Verabschiedungsrepertoire mit "Ade" ein bisschen begrenzt ist, brauchten was, was zu "lebe wohl" passt.

Deine Annahme ist also richtig - Für jemanden, den man in einem Monat wiedersehen wird, wird man den Gruß wohl eher nicht verwenden. Dort wo "leb wohl" passt, passt auch "ich wünsch' dir eine gute Zeit". Und lapidar mit "gleichfalls" zu antworten, passt eher nicht. Man würde eher "Ich ihnen/dir auch" antworten.

Comment: Ist hier in Oberbayern auch sehr gebräuchlich: _"I wünsch' Dia a guade Zeit"_, oder auch kurz: _"A guade Zeit"_. Meine bereits gelöschte Antwort kannst Du eh' sehen ;-)

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort! Da dies für meinen Fall zutrifft, markiere ich die Antwort als richtig - ich wohne tatsächlich im "Schwabenländle".  :) Das erklärt auch, warum es in dem von mir genannten Kontext verwendet wurde.

Answer (score 1):

Eine gute Zeit wünscht man, wenn man auf eine besondere Zeitspanne Bezug nimmt.

So könnte ein Hotelbetreiber den Gästen zur Begrüßung eine gute (Urlaubs-)Zeit wünschen, oder die Eltern dem Kind, das zu einem 12-monatigen Auslandspraktikum reist.

Für eine unbestimmte Zeit wird man jmd. kaum eine gute Zeit wünschen; sondern eher für eine bestimmte Zeit. Am Ende des Praktikums als Wunsch für den Rest des Lebens finde ich die Floskel daher eher ungewöhnlich.

Comment: _"Eine gute Zeit wünscht man, wenn man auf eine besondere Zeitspanne Bezug nimmt."_ Nicht zwingend. Hier regional wird es auch gleichbedeutend mit _"Lebewohl"_ verwendet.

Comment: "Hier regional" ist da, wo der SE-Server steht? Da Igor nicht schrieb wo er es gehört hat ist zweifelhaft, ob Informationen zur regionalen Verwendung weiterhelfen.

Comment: Hier regional ist Oberbayern, der Mittelpunkt der Welt! Was denkst Du denn? ;-)

Comment: Und Oberbayern ist Richtung Norden/Franken, nicht etwa oben wie Gebirge/Alpen - das ist Niederbayern, oder?

Comment: Rosenheim ist der Mittelpunkt der Welt, Du Ignorant ;-)

Comment: Ich, aus dem Nordosten Deutschlands stammend, kenne das auch nur im Zusammenhang mit Zeitabschnitten und nicht, wie in der anderen Antwort behauptet wird, mit finalen Abschieden.

Comment: Vielen Dank auch für diese Antwort! Es erstaunt mich immer wieder, wie sehr sich die Phrasen und Regeln im Deutschen zwischen den Regionen unterscheiden können :D